# codeigniter - jquery login function not calling/returning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, codeigniter-2

I have a login function in my controller that was getting called before, but i did some changes and it all just stopped.

I have a basic login with 2 inputs for a username/password and a submit

//Javascript

```
function initLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var d = {
        user: $('#userName').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    }

    console.log('test')//gets returned

    $.post('/cms/login/',d,function(data) {
        console.log(data);//nothing returning
    },'json');
}
```

//Controller

```
class CMS extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');

        //$this->_check_if_logged_in();
    }

    private function _check_if_logged_in() {
        if (!$this->uri->segment(2) || $this->uri->segment(2) == 'login') return FALSE;
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != TRUE) redirect('/cms');
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) redirect('/cms/home', 'refresh');

        $this->load->view('cms/log_in_view');
        $this->load->view('cms/parts/footer');
    }

    function login() {
        echo json_encode(array('test' => 'test'))//doesn't get echoed

        $data['user_name'] = $this->input->post('user');
        $data['pass_word'] = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

        $this->db->select('id');
        $res = $this->db->get_where('login',$data,1)->row_array();

        if (is_numeric($res['id'])) {
            $data['logged_in'] = TRUE;
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',TRUE);
        }

        echo json_encode($res);
    }
}
```

Basically i commented out everything that I thought might get in the way of returning a response, but this is going against everything I've learned.

I'm convinced the login function in the controller doesn't get called, even though it did before when i didn't change anything in the js or login function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One flaw I see is that if you find no row, `$res['id']` will make codeigniter print out a HTML error, which makes your json echo not work properly.

Try `if (!empty($res))` instead.

You can check with the Firebug Console (Addon in Firefox) what the ajax-request gave for an answer to see if more then the json was echo'd.

**Edit:**

Noticed that's not the real problem. Will read it again.

Try changing `class CMS extends CI_Controller` to `class Cms extends CI_Controller`

That is `CMS` -> `Cms`

Comment: no apparently your first answer is correct. $res['id'] wasn't found so it would end up breaking the whole function. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, try changin the URL, I don't know if this could work (because it should have returned you some error message in your console, like error 500 though).

Using "CMS" instead of "cms" shouldn't be a problem, but you can try that as well as @Robin Castlin pointed out.

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url("cms/login");?>',d,function(data) {
        console.log(data);//nothing returning
    },"json");
```

or, if can't use php here, use full url:

```
$.post('http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php/cms/login',d,function(data) {
        console.log(data);//nothing returning
    },"json");
```